# How does jsonschema map the raw json string value to python objects?

Tags: python, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

How does `jsonschema` work?

My assumption is that they convert the raw json strings they see into the python type that is listed in say `jsonschema.Draft4Validator.DEFAULT_TYPES` and see if it can be converted. If the convert is successful, then validation proceeds.

If that's the case, each of the types in python in `DEFAULT_TYPES` must have a "from string" method that converts a string to that type.

Is my understanding of `jsonschema` correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `jsonschema` operates on deserialized JSON (== Python objects), not strings. So the way it works is quite simple, each string type is mapped to a set of valid Python types, and validating that a thing is of the correct type is just an `isinstance` check.

You're correct that `DEFAULT_TYPES` is the default mapping used for that.

Comment: I held the wrong understanding as well, I was attempting to validate raw json strings not yet deserialized.

Comment: Is there a way to validate raw strings?